# SOAPUI response message

Tags: web-services, wsdl, soapui, xsd-validation

I am trying to call a web service using soap UI, here is the xml for the request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:uuid:e657a351-ae8c-42c5-b083-ebe5dcda5c0b">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:GetCustomerAccounts>
         <urn:CustomerLookup>
            <urn:CustomerIdentification>test</urn:CustomerIdentification>
            <urn:CustomerIdentificationValue>aptic</urn:CustomerIdentificationValue>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <urn:JuridicalType>?</urn:JuridicalType>
         </urn:CustomerLookup>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:CustomerOwnerReferenceFilter>?</urn:CustomerOwnerReferenceFilter>
      </urn:GetCustomerAccounts>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

No matter what I put on customerIdentification  and IdentificationValue

> ```
> Invalid enum value 'test' cannot be deserialized into type 'Aptic.WebIntegrationPlatform.Soap.Enums.CustomerIdentificationType
> Ensure that the necessary enum values are present and are marked with EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the type has
> ```
>
> DataContractAttribute attribute.

Here is the message:

```
<Message>The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter urn:uuid:e657a351-ae8c-42c5-b083-ebe5dcda5c0b:CustomerLookup. The InnerException message was 'Invalid enum value 'test' cannot be deserialized into type 'Aptic.WebIntegrationPlatform.Soap.Enums.CustomerIdentificationType'. Ensure that the necessary enum values are present and are marked with EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the type has DataContractAttribute attribute.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.</Message>
               <StackTrace><![CDATA[at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameter(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameters(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo[] parts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)]]></StackTrace>
               <Type>System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException</Type>
            </ExceptionDetail>
         </detail>
```

Any idea for the error ?

Here is [wsdl](https://ah-cctest01.aptic.net:7838/CustomerInformation/) for the service

Comment: what is your enum ? it seems that 'test' does not belong to it. Have you tried CustomerLookup as customeridentification? or another value from the wsdl ?

Comment: @A.Joly I did tried many options as enum; numbers, bool no luck. I added CustomerLookup right now same response. Any idea ?

Comment: well, until you can find where this enum is ...

Comment: @A.Joly is there any way to get those values information from wsdl ?

Comment: that's where my limitation is ... I'm not very familiar with wsdl and stuff, sorry :(

Comment: @A.Joly well thanks for your effort!

Comment: @trace_le, please check the answer to see if that is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the error is due to invalid value for the `CustomerIdentification` element in the request.

Use one of the below value for element `CustomerIdentification` in the request which you are sending based on the error message and wsdl file provided.

- Custom
- CustomerSESSNOrCompanyNo
- CustomerNOSSNOrCompanyNo
- CustomerReferenceNumber
- CustomerGuid

In order fix the error, you may have to provide the appropriate value for `CustomerIdentificationValue` element as well based on the chosen value for identification.

By the way, you can validate the soap request in SoapUI by *right click and validate* in the request editor (short cut is `Alt + v` key combination for the same).

Comment: totally did the job

Comment: @trace_le, glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <xs:simpleType name="CustomerIdentificationType">
       <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
           <xs:enumeration value="Custom"/>
           <xs:enumeration value="CustomerSESSNOrCompanyNo"/>
           <xs:enumeration value="CustomerNOSSNOrCompanyNo"/>
           <xs:enumeration value="CustomerReferenceNumber"/>
           <xs:enumeration value="CustomerGuid"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

Can you try this?

Comment: where should I add this ?

Comment: in request :                                                                                                     **<urn:CustomerIdentification>Custom</urn:CustomerIdentification>**

Comment: <Message>The prefix 'xs' is not defined. Line 6, position 92.</Message>